# Meteor.js : How to run check() when arguments are Mongodb ObjectId's?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In some of my Meteor methods, I'm sending Mongodb ObjectId's from the client as arguments. I'd like to run these through Meteor's check() system but I can't seem to find anything that matches successfully with them.

I've tried

```
var someObjectId = Meteor.Collection.ObjectId();

check(someObjectId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectId()) // fails
check(someObjectId, { _str : String }) //fails
check(someObjectId, String) //fails
```

any help much appreciated !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of:

```
check(someObjectId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID());
```

Try without the parentheses:

```
check(someObjectId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
```

Edit-

Note that the error message for this check isn't ideal.

```
check({}, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
// Error: Match error: Expected
```

You *could* assume the message should be something like

```
// Error: Match error: Expected ObjectId, got object
```

You can see why this happens in this snippet from the check package.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/check/match.js

```
if (pattern instanceof Function) {
    if (value instanceof pattern)
        return;
    // XXX what if .name isn't defined
    throw new Match.Error("Expected " + pattern.name);
}
```

`Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` does not have `name` property.

Comment: Thanks again for your help - in fact i was forgetting to capitalise the last 'd' : the correct syntax is Meteor.Collection.ObjectID

Comment: Any idea why when I run `check("Lfvdn83gqdTMGmd5a", Meteor.Collection.ObjectID)` I get `Error: Match error: Expected particular constructor`?

Comment: You are getting that error (expected particular constructor), because you are comparing a string to the object id.  You would have to run a  check(new Mongo.ObjectID("Lfvdn83gqdTMGmd5a"), Meteor.Collection.ObjectID) or create your own match.where function.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, you could simply pass the hexadecimal string as an argument instead of the ObjectID.

```
var idValidator = Match.Where(function (id) {
    check(id, String);
    return /[0-9a-fA-F]{24}/.test(id);
});

check(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID()._str, idValidator);
// success

check('', idValidator);
// Error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation

check({}, idValidator);
// Error: Match error: Expected string, got object

check([], idValidator);
// Error: Match error: Expected string, got object <--- bug? I expect array
```

Note, this regular expression is pulled from here.

https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js

Answer (score 1):

You should use following to generate a random ObjectID:

```
var someObjectId = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID();
```

As Cuberto said, you can then check it by `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`:

```
check(someObjectId, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally when using `check()` you're not in a position to generate a new Meteor `_id`. Here's an alternative using `Match.check()`

First extend the `Match` object with:

```
Match._id = Match.Where(function (id) {
  check(id, String);
  return /[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,17}/.test(id);
});
```

This is useful because you're likely to be checking `_id`s in many of your methods.

Now simply:

```
check(_id,Match._id);
```

[more on this pattern](http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/12/meteor-security-no-4-extending-match.html)

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer to the original question:

First, define a matcher for a single object in your array of arguments:

```
Match._id = Match.Where(function (id) {
  check(id, String);
  return /[a-zA-Z0-9]{17,17}/.test(id);
});
```

Then you can call:

```
check(MyArrayOfArguments, [Match._id])
```